# How to create a class with a UIViewController when the subclass of UIViewController is unknown

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

The title is what I think I need but i will go back one step.  I want to create a class which handles certain things in an iOS app.  This class might be called by multiple `UIViewcontrollers` in an iOS app.  The class may need to show a `UIView` at some stage for user input.  So my question is how can I show a `UIView` when I don't know which `subclass` of `UIViewController` is calling it?  To what can I add the `UIView` from this class?

I suppose there are two possible answers either the class finds the current `UIViewController` or the calling subclass of `UIViewController` passes itself to the class so the class knows.

How is this supposed to be done.

Thanks guys for your help.

Comment: Why do you need to know which class is the caller?

Comment: ClassA, ClassB, ClassC etc all exist in an iOS app.  They all are subclasses of UIViewController or UITableViewController or some other Controller class.  They all might alloc and init ClassX - "call a method of ClassX" or however you want to say it. How can ClassX show a UIView?

Comment: @protocol and subclassing

Comment: I'm blown away Eric by your comprehensive clear answers. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Either I'm missing something or you're trying to subvert some of the basic premises of object-oriented design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to expand on @ericleaf's comment regarding using a protocol and subclasses. It sounds like you are asking the following:

> How can I create a resusable, generic class that presents a view
>   within a UIViewController subclass?

A great way to do this is to define a protocol in your generic class and have your view controller subclasses support this protocol. The protocol defines an interface for your custom class to comunicate with it's `delegate`, in this case a `UIViewController` subclass. Other than the protocol, the objects don't need to know anything else about the implementation of each other.

Any information your custom object needs to be able to present views within it's delegate would be passed via protocol methods. The specifics of the protocol are up to you based on your needs. You could have the custom object "ask" the delegate for information (e.g. what view should I put a subview in?) or you could have the protocol provide information to the delegate and let the delegate deal with it (e.g. here is a subview you can put wherever you want).

There is a lot of great documentation on protocols available on SO and elsewhere. This is long enough already so I kept the example fairly simple.

### custom class .h file with protocol definition

```
// my custom class that adds adds a view to a view controller that supports it's protocol

// forward class definition for the protocol
@class MyAwesomeObject;

@protocol MyAweseomeObjectDelegate <NSObject>
- (UIView *)viewForMyAwesomeObject:(MyAwesomeObject *)awesomeObject;
@end

// this could be defined such that the delegate *must* be a UIViewController. I've left it generic.
@interface MyAwesomeClassObject : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <MyAwesomeObjectDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

### custom class .m file

```
// MyAwesomeObject.m

#import "MyAwesomeObject.h"

@implementation MyAwesomeObject

// this is a dumb example, but shows how to get the view from the delegate
// and add a subview to it
- (void)presentViewInDelegate
{
    UIView *containingView = [self.delegate viewForMyAwesomeObject:self];
    if (containingView) {
        UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:containingView.bounds];
        subview.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        subview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [containingView addSubview:subview];
    }
}
```

### MyViewController .h using the custom object

```
// MyViewController.h

@import "MyAwesomeObject.h"

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <MyAwesomeObjectDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyAwesomeObject *awesomeObject;
@end
```

### MyViewController .m using the custom object

```
// MyViewController.m

@import "MyViewController.h"

@implementation MyViewController

- (void)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _awesomeObject = [[MyAwesomeObject alloc] init];
        _awesomeObject.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}

// MyAwesomeObjectDelegate
- (UIView *)viewForMyAwesomeObject:(MyAwesomeObject *)awesomeObject
{
    return self.view;
}
```

Comment: Although delegation is great for communicating between classes, isn't this a bit of an overkill to present a view. And when I know its always gonna be a UIViewController subclass why delegate? Why would I go for a delegate when I have a view and frame, all directly accessible?

Comment: Overkill is subjective. Delegation is very easy to implement and encapsulates logic nicely. I don't know exactly what @darbid is trying to accomplish and how extensible/adaptable/re-usable he wants his solution to be. Generally, when thinking about external interfaces (e.g. an SDK) it is preferential to define things where logic is clearly encapsulated as with delegation. If all that's needed is a way for an object to add a subview to an arbitrary view controller's view, then sure, can do that simply with access `viewController.view`.

Comment: Thank you XJones very much for a well thought out solution.  What I don't understand is why cannot in my Custom class I have a UIViewController property. Then any class using the custom class can use this property as long as the class has UIViewController as its superclass? I am obviously not a programming expert but I thought this is how it works in java for example.(Java is JUST an example I know we are in Objective c)

Comment: You can do that. If all you need is access to properties/methods defined by `UIViewController` that's fine. I almost suggested that but gave you info on delegation b/c I didn't know exactly what you needed to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the class into a string and do a compare.

For example, lets assume your custom `UIViewController` subclass is `CustomViewCon` and the `UIViewController` object reference is `myUnknownClassObject`, then:

```
NSString *classString = NSStringFromClass([myUnknownClassObject class]);
```

Then you can:

```
if([classString isEqualToString:@"CustomViewCon"]){
    //do something like maybe present a particular view
    myUnknownClassObject.view = myCustomView; //or anything..
}
```

Similarly you can check for any class.

Edit: According to the suggestions from comments, you could also do the following(better way):

```
if([[myUnknownClassObject class] isKindOfClass:[CustomViewCon class]]){
    //same as before
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest comparing classes using `-isKindOfClass:`, so you're not introducing dependencies on string literals and so that inheritance works as expected.

Comment: This requires I keep a list of names in this class, that is not my idea of a reusable class. Surely there be another way. Must I use the id class for example?

Comment: @darbid: id is not a class. Its a type. Also why use `id` when you know all your classes will be `UIViewController` or its subclasses?
I have updated my answer to one which does not involve string literals. (Thanks to @SeamusCampbell) Dumb of me to not think of it before. That was the more obvious solution. :)

Comment: Yes that can work, that s good and is a possible solution. But if I take this class and put it into a new app I would have to go in and change it around. I cannot imagine this to be the best or widely used solution. It is for example obviously not the solution that an add on sdk uses for example when it presents a view.

Comment: What do you have in mind? Your problem is somewhat specific and hence the somewhat specific solution. And this is a solution only for checking the kind of class not presenting a view. If you could elaborate on the add-on sdk part, it would be easier to understand and maybe I could help. But for identifying the class of an ambiguous object from a set of classes, this is a simple solution .

Comment: yep I agree Rakesh.  Your answer is a solution.  it appears I can only make one my choice though and as I know how to do protocols etc I will do this one.  It seems to be a better way of making my class "reusable".

Answer (score 0):

Why wont you use a block for this?
BaseViewController.h:

```
@property (copy) void (^addViewBlock)();
- (IBAction)showViewWhenNeeded;
```

BaseViewController.m:

```
- (IBAction)showViewWhenNeeded
{
    if (self.addViewBlock)
        self.addViewBlock();
}
```

And in your child class, set that block's actions, and call the method when you feel like you should put up a view.

ChildViewController.m

```
// within some method, propably init or smth
[self setAddViewBlock:^{
    [self.vied addSubView:...];
}];

// when need to actually add the view
[self showViewWhenNeeded];
```